Was Eve created for rescue rather than assistance?
Gen.2.18 says Eve was created to be "Ezer K'Negdo": "וַיֹּאמֶר י"א לֹא־טוֹב הֱיוֹת הָאָדָם לְבַדּוֹ אֶעֱשֶׂהּ־לּוֹ עֵזֶר כְּנֶגְדּוֹ׃".
I looked up the usage of עזר in the Tanakh and all I could find was some kind of "rescue" or "deliverance", not mere "assistance in daily chores". Compare:

"וְשֵׁ֥ם הָאֶחָ֖ד אֱלִיעֶ֑זֶר כִּֽי־אֱלֹהֵ֤י אָבִי֙ בְּעֶזְרִ֔י וַיַּצִּלֵ֖נִי מֵחֶ֥רֶב פַּרְעֹֽה׃"
"ק֭וּמָֽה עֶזְרָ֣תָה לָּ֑נוּ וּ֝פְדֵ֗נוּ לְמַ֣עַן חַסְדֶּֽךָ׃"
"אֱלֹהִ֣ים לָ֭נוּ מַחֲסֶ֣ה וָעֹ֑ז עֶזְרָ֥ה בְ֝צָרֹ֗ות נִמְצָ֥א מְאֹֽד׃"
"שִׁ֗יר לַֽמַּ֫עֲלֹ֥ות אֶשָּׂ֣א עֵ֭ינַי אֶל־הֶהָרִ֑ים מֵ֝אַ֗יִן יָבֹ֥א עֶזְרִֽי׃"
"אֱלֹהִ֥ים לְהַצִּילֵ֑נִי יְ֝הוָ֗ה לְעֶזְרָ֥תִי חֽוּשָֽׁה׃"
"הַאִ֬ם אֵ֣ין עֶזְרָתִ֣י בִ֑י וְ֝תֻשִׁיָּ֗ה נִדְּחָ֥ה מִמֶּֽנִּי׃"
"אֹ֣ורוּ מֵרֹ֗וז אָמַר֙ מַלְאַ֣ךְ יְהוָ֔ה אֹ֥רוּ אָרֹ֖ור יֹשְׁבֶ֑יהָ כִּ֤י לֹֽא־בָ֨אוּ֙ לְעֶזְרַ֣ת יְהוָ֔ה לְעֶזְרַ֥ת יְהוָ֖ה בַּגִּבֹּורִֽים׃"

Unkelos also translates closer to "resque" than "assistance": "אַעֲבֵד לֵהּ סְמַךְ לְקִבְלֵהּ:".
Jastrow online (עֵזֶר), however, provides only the later interpretation based on the verse in Genesis. And so do most traditional interpreters - "Eve was created as an assistance to Adam".
Based on the use of the word in the rest of Taanakh, can the original intention of God in the creation of Eve be different? Maybe to save him from the sin of bestiality (see Yevamot.63a?

Where do you get סמך = rescue? Jastrow has "support, help".

@magicker72 סמך is "to rely on something", therefore לסמוך על not לסמוך ל.

The idea is connected to why kallah goes 7 circles around chassan, but they joke nowadays, afterthefact it's another way around. R. Eisenman makes a big discussion out of the fact that when a woman asked Adam to eat from a tree, he follows without any resistance.

The English “help” connotes a secondary role, simply supporting or completing someone else’s job. The Biblical Hebrew עזר has no such connotation: it rather indicates partnership, in a context where such partnership is entirely necessary. They are NOT the same.

@QwertyCTRL. I brought up enough verses that Biblical עזר does NOT indicate partnership but rescue. If you have another interpretation, please provide Biblical sources for "partnership".

It’s possible, as the Or HaChaim suggests, that she did save him from the sin of bestiality:

ויאמר ה' וגו' לא טוב וגו'. קשה הלא כבר ביום ברא אלהים אדם זכר ונקבה
ברא אותם, עוד קשה אומרו סמוך לו אעשה לו עזר כנגדו וגומר ויצר וגומר כל
חית השדה, שנראה שרצה לזווג לו חית השדה וזה פלא לזווג אדם ובהמה, ועוד
שיסיר נקבת בהמה או חיה מבן זוגה ולזווגה עם האדם, עליונים למטה ותחתונים
למעלה, עוד קשה אומרו ויפל ה' תרדמה וגו', וכי לא היה ה' יכול לברוא לו
בת זוגו עפר מן האדמה. מלבד מה שהקשינו שמצינו לו שברא לו בת זוגו ביום
הבראו וכמו שהעיד הכתוב אחר כן זכר ונקבה בראם וגו' ביום הבראם ורז"ל
אמרו דרשות רבות וצריכין פותר אבל פשט הכתוב לא מצאנוהו:  ויאמר השם
אלוקים לא טוב.
The Lord G'd said: "It is not good for man to be alone, etc." This is
difficult since G'd had mentioned already on the day He created man
that the species had been created male and female (1,27). Another
problem in the text is the expression אעשה, "I shall make for him a
helpmate." The Torah then immediately proceeds to describe that the
mammals and the birds were formed, i.e. ויצר השם אלוקים (2,19). This
gives the impression that G'd intended one of these animals to be
man's helpmate. Such a thought is not only extremely strange, but if
true it would also result in one of those animals being deprived of
its own mate! Besides, why did G'd have to put Adam to sleep and to
remove part of his body? Could He not have formed woman as dust from
the earth as He had formed man himself, especially since He formed Eve
on the very same day He formed Adam (5,2) זכר ונקבה בראם? Our sages
have given many homiletical explanations in answer to these questions,
but they have not provided us with פשט, straightforward answers that
justify the text as it stands.

Or HaChaim:

ונראה לפי מה שקדם מדברי רז"ל (עירובין יח) כי אדם וחוה דו פרצופין נבראו
למאן דאמר פרצוף, ולמאן דאמר זנב, כדאיתא במס' שבת, וכפי זה זאת האשה וזה
בניינה כי מתחלה בראה דבוקה עמו ממש למ"ד כסברתו ולמ"ד כסברתו. ובסדר זה
ישנם גם כן בהכנת המוליד דהלא תמצא שאמר ה' להם (א' כח) פרו ורבו וגו'
קודם הנסירה הא למדת שהכינם ה' להוליד גם בהיותם בסדר זה וזאת האשה אשר
נסר ה' ולקחה ממקום דביקתה אשר בראה ביום הבראם.
We may have to fall back on the opinions expressed in Berachot 61 that
originally man was created with two faces in one body. The Talmud
there offers two opinions as to what was removed from Adam, a tail or
a face, respectively. This is a reasonable explanation because it
justifies G'd's blessing or command to Adam to be fruitful and to
multiply (1,28) at a time when woman had not yet been reported as a
separate entity.

Brachot 61a:

אִי נָמֵי כִּדְרַבִּי יִרְמְיָה בֶּן אֶלְעָזָר. דְּאָמַר רַבִּי
יִרְמְיָה בֶּן אֶלְעָזָר: דּוּ פַּרְצוּפִין בָּרָא הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ
הוּא בָּאָדָם הָרִאשׁוֹן, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: ״אָחוֹר וָקֶדֶם צַרְתָּנִי״.
Alternatively, this duplication in the language of creation can be
explained in accordance with the statement of Rabbi Yirmeya ben
Elazar, as Rabbi Yirmeya ben Elazar said: The Holy One, Blessed be He,
created two faces [du partzufin] on Adam the first man; he was created
both male and female in a single body, as it is stated: “You have
formed me [tzartani] behind and before” (Psalms 139:5); tzartani is
derived from the word tzura [face]. God formed two faces on a single
creation, back and front.

We can translate כנגדו as “facing,” according to this reading.
Holding a person accountable is a necessary part of any relationship. If we accept the interpretation of Rabbi Yirmeya ben Elazar, the hermaphroditic two-faced Adam would not be able to do so insofar as it requires “facing” a person.
Animals have many parallels to human faces, but they don’t have the level of intelligence that we have, and looking an animal in the eye yields a different experience. Animals can’t hold us to account for our actions.
Rabbi Shraga Silverstein translates it as follows, based on Rashi:
“[I shall make him a help [(If he merits it, she is a help)], against him [(If he does not merit it, she is against him, contending with him)].”
She helps him not “just by assistance in daily chores” but by withholding her help from him if he does not merit it. This means that G-d gives her the power to discern his merit.

I've upvoted your answer but your ending doesn't really lead from your last source. I think you should flesh it out a bit more
